# Center align image in a div

Tags: html, css

I would like to align an image in a `<div>`, without using any IDs. All of the solutions I've seen have used IDs or classes. I don't want to use those.

**CSS**

```
div {
    text-align: left;
 }

div img{
    //Tried many things but no luck
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <img src="dd.png" />
</div>
```

How can I center all the images in a div?

Comment: Just target it the same way you are already doing it, but apply the styles shown in those answers

Comment: Thanks @IvanS95 for making my points for me. OP, you need the right CSS, it's not specific to ID's or div vs. img.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about why your current code have default `text-align: left` for `div` element.

But please try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/18230pwa/

```
div img {
    display : block;
    margin : auto;
}

div {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`div {
text-align: center;
}`

`<div> 
//Image link
</div>`

you don't need to specifically target the image. if the image is in the div, it will be centered. you could also use the `<center>` tag which functions similarly.

if you aren't looking to center it, just use the text-align method above but use the keyword right or left.